# Need some help building a somewhat simple REGEX expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to build a somewhat REGEX expression of the of only numbers including decimal with a maximum of 3 numbers to the right of the decimal (thousandths) and 50 to the left. Valid entries would like something like these.

```
1
1.0
.1
1.011
.011
1202938.123
1237923782.0
```

So far I have `^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*){1,999}$`.. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to match only 50 digits, why you have `{1,999}` in your original regex?

Comment: Which language are you coding in?

Comment: I am using a the `RegularExpressionValidator` in ASP. I found that expression online doing a Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should suffice:

```
^(?=.)\d{0,50}(?:\.\d{0,3})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdDCRm/1). Note this will also match `1.`, if this is undesired change `\d{0,3}` to `\d{1,3}`. Similarely, this regex will match `.5` (with no integer part), if you dont want this then use `\d{1,50}` instead of `\d{0,50}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
^(?=.+)\d{0,50}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

**[Demonstration here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9VODQU/5)**

## Explanation -

`^` tells the regex that the match will begin at the start of the string,
`\d{0, 50}` matches 0 - 50 digits,
`(?=.+)` is a positive look-ahead, that tells the regex that the matching should only start if the line contains some characters in it (as rightly pointed out in the comments!),
`(?:\.\d{1,3})?` matches an optional dot (`.`), followed by 1 - 3 digits,
`$` tells the regex that whatever it has matched so far will be followed by the end of the string.

Comment: Your pattern matches also the empty string. (and with pcre, the pattern will succeed also if the string ends with a newline character, but it doesn't matter since there's no language tag in the question.)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for bringing that to my notice!

Answer (score 0):

Other way: You can check if the string isn't empty and if the dot is always followed by digits, putting a word-boundary at a strategic place:

```
^\d{0,50}\.?\b\d{0,3}$
```

As you can see, all is optional in the pattern except the word-boundary that does the magic.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/GvFJfj/1)